# jQuery on click $(document) - get clicked element

Tags: jquery, click, hide

I'm trying to figure out how to get the clicked element whey using $(document).click() method:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if ($(this) !== obj) {
        obj2.hide();
    }
});
```

In the example above the **obj** is the object is the dropdown menu - and if clicked I don't want it to do anything, but if the click was on the body of the page or any other element - it should trigger the hide() method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). You should also compare DOM elements instead of jQuery objects, since two jQuery objects containing the same elements will still be considered as different:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target !== obj[0]) {
        obj2.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic - isn't it possible with the jquery object? - the obj is the : var obj = $(this).find('.topNavigation'); - so it is referring to the specific object?

Comment: I've tried it this way, but without any luck: if (event.target !== $('.topNavigation')) - any idea?

Comment: Since `obj` was returned by `find()`, it's a jQuery object. These objects are compared by reference, not by content, which is why they're considered as different even if they contain the same elements. Using `$(".topNavigation")[0]` gives you the DOM element back, which you can then compare.

Comment: Frederic - many thanks - it works now! I've tried with obj[0] - and it also works - so problem solved - much appreciate your help.

Comment: note that it won't work if you have more than one element with that class or if a child element of it was clicked

Comment: But doesn't : $(".topNavigation")[0] - refer to any element with this class on the page? I'm only interested in the one which was triggered - is there a way of doing it?

Comment: That was not clear from your question, but in that case @Esailija's answer is more appropriate, and you should accept it instead of mine.

Comment: @user398341 `$(".topNavigation")[0]` refers to the first element jQuery found in the page with that class,  `$(".topNavigation")[1]` to the second and so on..

Comment: @Esailija - that's what I thought it does - thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 14):

You most likely want to check all parent elements + the target itself for `.topNavigation` class

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ( !$(event.target).closest( ".topNavigation" ).length ) {
        obj2.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this will work better with what I'm looking for as it also refers to the items, which overlay the topNavigation container and are inside if it - great tip - thank you!

Comment: Worked well. I used console.log(event.target) to find which element was getting clicked.