# About javascript showbox,I need some help! online~~

Tags: javascript, show-hide

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="ppp">button</button>
    <div id="content" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>​
```

if i click the button,the content will be show(open),

if the content is on show(open),when i click document(except the content),the content will be close.

> var $ = function (id){
>         return !id ? null : document.getElementById(id);
>       }
>
> ```
> var addEventSimple = function(obj, evt, fn) {
>     if (obj.addEventListener){ // W3C
>         obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
>     }else if (obj.attachEvent) // Microsoft
>         obj.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
> }
>
>
>
> var button = $('ppp'),
>     content = $('content');
>
>
> var init = function() {};
>
> init.handleObj = button;
> init.showbox = content;    
> init.flag = false;
> init.allowcls = false;    
> init.open = function () {//open the content
>         if (this.flag == false) {
>             this.showbox.style.display = "block";
>             this.flag = true;
>             this.allowcls = true;
>         }
>     };
> init.close =  function () { // close the content
>         if (this.flag && this.allowcls) {
>                 this.showbox.style.display = "none";
>                 this.flag = false;
>                 this.allowcls = false;
>         }
>     };
> init.load = function() { // button click
>         //e = e ||window.event;
>         //e.preventDefault();
>         if (this.flag) {
>             this.close();
>         } else {
>             this.open();
>         }
>     };
> init.clickClose = function(e) { // document click
>
>         if (!this.allowcls) {
>             return;
>         }
>         e = e ||window.event;
>         var target = e.target;
>         if (target === this.showbox) { // button
>             return;
>         }       
>          this.close();
> };
>
>
> addEventSimple(button, 'click', function (){
>     init.load();//the code run here OK
> })// error on here,but i don't know why?
> addEventSimple(document, 'click', function (e){
>     init.clickClose(e);
> })
> ```

code in here :http://jsfiddle.net/DCty3/

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery? If you are, what is the reason, you are not using it? It allows to use much less code to do much more stuff. Any way, your "question" is not really formed as question.

Comment: i understand jQuery ，But javascript is more important ，jquery can't do all.

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript library. You given "problem" is trivial jQuery problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle element display, you can use function like this:

```
function toggleDisplay(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.style.display = (elem.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '');
}
```

There is unlimited id toggle script too:

```
function toggle() {
    for ( var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        elem.style.display = (elem.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
    }
}
```

With jQuery it will be just:

```
function toggleDisplay(id) {
    $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

I like getting fancy with objects, here is another multifunctional method:

```
var display = {
    show : function() {
        for ( i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
            document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.display = '';
        }
    },
    hide : function() {
        for ( i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
            document.getElementById(arguments[i]).style.display = 'none';
        }
    },
    toggle : function() {
        for ( i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
            elem.style.display = (elem.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
        }
    }
};
```

To use it, do something like this:

```
display.show('content','content2','content3');
display.hide('content','content2','content3');
display.toggle('content','content2','content3');
```

For convenience, you can add another function to enable button:

```
function toggleDisplayButton(bId, cId) {
    document.getElementById(bId).onclick = (function() {
        toggleDisplay(cId);
    });
}
window.onload = (function() {
    toggleDisplayButton('ppp','content');
});
```

To enable function, when user clicks "outside" the box, and it closes, there is used an easy trick, by creating another element in background, that covers all area around:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="ppp">button</button>
    <div id="outerBox" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="content" style="display:none;">1</div>
</div>
```

CSS should make your container relative positioned and "trick box", absolutely positioned, with maximum size of screen, and z-indexed under container like this:

```
#content{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#efefef;border:1px solid #555555;z-index:56;position:relative;}
#outerBox{width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:55;}
```

And make it work like this:

```
var display = {
    toggle : function() {
        for ( i=0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
            elem.style.display = (elem.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
        }
    }
};
function toggleBox() {
    document.getElementById('ppp').onclick = (function() {
        display.toggle('content','outerBox');
    });
    document.getElementById('outerBox').onclick = (function() {
        display.toggle('content','outerBox');
    });
}
onload = function() {
    toggleBox();
}
```

The result looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Deele/PSNwv/).

Comment: ??? toggle the ppp is the one , the second,if the content is on show(open),when i click document(except the content),the content will be close.

Comment: What did you just said? I don't understand.

Comment: thanks,but this don't i want to.  i find my error,may be it is event(e). when i change the event, it work . http://jsfiddle.net/DCty3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is exactly same as this one:-

Check out this post :-
[jQuery on click $(document) - get clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945825/jquery-on-click-document-get-clicked-element)

Hope this will help.

Comment: :`var $ = function (id){
  return !id ? null : document.getElementById(id);
}` use to shorten the document.getElementById,what happen??