# how to get specific element from jQuery 'body' click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

if I have the following:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
  //alert($(this).attr('class')); alerts undefined because 'body' has no class
});
```

how can I get the specific element that was clicked on?

basically what I'm doing is, if anything on the body is clicked do one thing, but if its a specific element, do something else. so I'm checking the class, but that's not working

something like:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('specific') {
    //do specific();
  } else {
    //do generic();
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to look into **event delegation**. basically, what you want is `$('body').on("click","*",function(){//stuff...});` which says, if a child of `body` is clicked and matches selector `*` (anything) than do `//stuff...`. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945825/jquery-on-click-document-get-clicked-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.target`

```js
$("body").on("click", function(event) {
    alert(event.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<button>This is a button</button>
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: why u gotta be a life saver like this? :)

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be to check the documentation here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

As you will see there are a few things you can do with a mouse click:
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Without knowing what exactly you want to do; the advice given to you by Richard Hamilton above is probably the best.